# Java Monopoly Game

Tags: java, loops

I made a Board and I set the board's layout to null. So I position my token's by moving them pixel by pixel. But when turning the corners I am having a trouble. After first 10 position token can make the turn and continue for the next 10 position. But it is impossible for my token to make the 2. turn.
Can anyone advice me a better code for this problem. I think I make things get more complicated than it is.

```
            if(g.getPosx() <= 650 && g.getPosx() >= 50 && g.getPosy()==650) {
            if(g.getPosx()-unitChange*d.getDice() <= 50) {
                temp = unitChange*d.getDice() - (g.getPosx() - 50);
                g.setPosx(50);
                g.setPosy(g.getPosy()-temp);
            }
            else {
                g.setPosx(g.getPosx()-unitChange*d.getDice());  
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(g.getPosy() <= 650 && g.getPosy() >= 50 && g.getPosx()==650) {
            if(g.getPosy()-unitChange*d.getDice() <= 50) {
                temp = unitChange*d.getDice() - (g.getPosy() - 50);
                g.setPosy(50);
                g.setPosx(g.getPosx()-temp);
            }
            else {
                g.setPosy(g.getPosy()-unitChange*d.getDice());  
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(g.getPosx() <= 650 && g.getPosx() >= 50 && g.getPosy()==50) {
            if(g.getPosx()-unitChange*d.getDice() <= 50) {
                temp = unitChange*d.getDice() - (g.getPosx() - 50);
                g.setPosx(50);
                g.setPosy(g.getPosy()-temp);
            }
            else {
                g.setPosx(g.getPosx()-unitChange*d.getDice());      
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
        else if(g.getPosy() <= 650 && g.getPosy() >= 50 && g.getPosx()==50) {
            if(g.getPosy()-unitChange*d.getDice() <= 50) {
                temp = unitChange*d.getDice() - (g.getPosy() - 50);
                g.setPosy(50);
                g.setPosx(g.getPosx()-temp);
            }
            else {
                g.setPosy(g.getPosy()-unitChange*d.getDice());  
                temp = 0;   
            }
        }
```

Comment: You've got a lot of magic numbers in this code

Comment: Perhaps try Codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @AndyTurner The code does not work as intended (2nd turn not working correctly) which unfortunately makes it off-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the current X and Y positions to track which location the piece is stopped on, try tracking which property the piece has landed on instead. so property 1 would be the first stop on the board after GO all the way up to boardwalk at position 39. Then you can have a function like

```
movePlayerToLocation(Player player, int location){

    // calculate your x and y based on the property locatoin

    if(locatoin < 11){
      // on first edge
    } else if (location < 21) {
      // on second edge
    } else if (location < 31) 
      // on third edge
    } else {
      // on fourth edge of the board
    }

  // do your g.setPos-ing
}
```